# Multiple IF statement looking for specific text or it goes to another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've built a worksheet that has employee identifier, employee name, manager identifier, and whether the manager is just a manager or if they are a director or exec.

It basically looks like this, except it has a lot more columns (general idea attached).

I want to have an IF statement (or whatever) in column J that says something like: if the employee's manager doesn't have the span of control of either director or executive, then go to his manager's manager (and do the same thing until you get to a director or executive).

Can I do that? If so, how?

***Example picture***
[image]

Comment: Are there more levels of employees than shown in the picture?

Comment: Yes. I think I got it though: 
=IF(F2="Director",D2,IF(F2="Executive",D2,IF(I2="Director",G2,IF(I2="Executive",G2,IF(L2="Director",J2,IF(L2="Executive",J2,IF(O2="Director",M2,IF(O2="Executive",M2,"ERROR"))))))))

Comment: I see....you could simplify that a bit using OR - =IF(OR(F2="Director",F2="Executive"),D2,IF(OR(I2="Director",I2="Executive"),G2,IF(OR(L2="Director",L2="Executive"),J2,IF(OR(O2="Director",O2="Executive‌​"),M2,"ERROR"))))

Comment: Hm... That's a great idea too. Thanks!